# How to run code before initial view opens?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

i want to run this code before the initial view controller even opens the view so the app knows where to redirect the user if the user is logged in. how can i do that? the code is here:

```
if let firstCheck = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("username"){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("View1ToView2Segue", sender: nil)
}
```

i put the code after ***override func viewDidLoad()*** but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that. :( In this case, I would have a load image or something similar and have it fade away if the segue is not supposed to be performed. You would run this in the `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: ok. i know i cannot have any code attached to the launchscreen.storyboard. so do you have a way to create a custom launch screen with code?

Comment: I don't believe you understanding me correctly. You do not need to do anything in the launchscreen.storyboard. If this is your first viewController, then put an image or some text in the launchscreen. Then put the same thing on top of your viewcontroller. If you have multiple views, add a view on top of your viewcontroller, then add the separate views on top of that

Comment: If my answer helped you,could you please accept it? Thanks